# Elastic search equivalent to left join

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the brands filter on our e-commerce website. Indented behavior is to still show all the brands even though any brand had been selected, only the items shown should be filtered on the selected brand.

My search:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match": {  
                "text": {
                    "query":"photo"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": { "brandName": "brodit" }
          }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": { 
  "Brands": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "brandName"
    }
  }
}
```

My intention and what I get:

[image]

As I can see this is happening because I am limiting the results based on the filter and making the aggeration on the filtered results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: When performing an aggregation you can specify that you want to perform the aggregation across all of the documents. This can be accomplished by setting the scope for the aggregation to use the [Global Bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html#_global_bucket). Here is a modified version of your query.

```
"query": {
"bool": {
    "must": {
        "match": {  
            "text": {
                "query":"photo"
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": [
      {
        "term": { "brandName": "brodit" }
      }
    ]
  }
},
  "aggs": { 
    "Brands": {
      "global": {},
      "terms": {
        "field": "brandName"
    }
}
```

}

Please see the [Global Bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html#_global_bucket) section of the [Elasticsearch: Definitive Guide [2.x]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) documentation for more details.

Alternately you can execute two queries. One query which returns no search results (by setting size=0) to obtain your aggregation on the brands for your filter options to display. Then when a user selects a specific brand to filter by, you will need to execute a separate query without aggregation to show only the items that belong to that brand in the search results.

Comment: I think you are right, that I can do it using 2 requests. It would have been nicer if for ex. using some kind of query joins etc., I could do it in one request.

Comment: Dug in a little deeper and found that there is a global scope available for aggregations. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate it. But I would like the brands in the query context but not in the brand context. So global will not work, because it will give me all of our brands. Even if the query does not match with them. Otherwise I have to apply the query filter on the brands aggs along with the global scope.

Comment: I have used your suggestion using global along with the filters(for query), that has solved my issue :)